# Getting wrong version of packages using Conda

Tags: python, conda

I have conda on a machine without root privileges. I have been using IPython and other packages on an environment called `py36` for Python3.6. I'm gonna focus here on IPython because it's easier, but it happens to other stuff like xarray.

According to conda everything is up to date. So if I issue `conda list` I get:

```
# packages in environment at ~/miniconda3/envs/py36:                                                                                                           
#                                                                                                                                                                            
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel                                                                                                           
.
.
.
ipython                   7.3.0            py36h39e3cac_0
```

I confirm that I'm using the correct IPython with

```
(py36) [myuser@mypc ~]$ which ipython
~/miniconda3/envs/py36/bin/ipython
```

However, I have an older version of IPython when I actually use it:

```
(py36) [myuser@mypc ~]$ ipython --version
7.1.1
```

This doesn't make much sense to me, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Where did `IPython 7.3.0` go?

Comment: Do you know how IPython was installed in the first place? Could you uninstall IPython and then reinstall it using conda?

Comment: @Sheldon thanks for the tip. I don't remember ever using anything other than `conda`, but it worked when I issued `pip uninstall`. I still don't understand what was going on though.